# sequential pandas rolling data processing

Tags: pandas, python-3.6, sequential

I´m working with pandas rolling-function to generate sequential data. My main window size is 51 and I need to calculate various measures from this initial window with different windows,e.g.:
dummy data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,800,size=(1000, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
```

My function:

```
def test(data):
     meanMov = np.zeros((51,3))
     mean = np.mean(data[0:31,:],axis=0)
     for i in range(0,16):
         meanMov[i] = mean
     mean = np.mean(data[20:50,:], axis=0)
     for i in range(35,51):
         meanMov[i] = mean
     for i in range(16,35):
         meanMov[i] = np.mean(data[(i-15):(i+15+1)], axis=0)
     return meanMov.mean()
```

To run the function:

```
r = df.rolling(51)
 entr = (r.apply(test)).dropna(axis=0, how='all')
```

when I run the function I got the following error:

```
>>> entr =  (r.apply(test)).dropna(axis=0, how='all')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 1207, in apply
    return super(Rolling, self).apply(func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 856, in apply
    center=False)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 799, in _apply
    result = np.apply_along_axis(calc, self.axis, values)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 116, in apply_along_axis
    res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 795, in calc
    closed=self.closed)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 853, in f
    offset, func, args, kwargs)
  File "pandas\_libs\window.pyx", line 1450, in pandas._libs.window.roll_generic (pandas\_libs\window.c:36061)
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in test
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

How can I calculate the different means for all columns and save them for further processing...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are `mid` and `calc_entropy`? What does your desired output look like? Have you tried `pd.rolling_mean(df, window = 51).dropna()`?

Comment: mid=16 and calc_entropy was the previous name of the function, sorry for this, I changed it! I need to calculate three different means per column individually. If values in the rolling window are above a distinct threshold, rolling values are replaced by the means which works great outside pd.rolling...

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,800,size=(1000, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

# To include this data into the dataframe with rolling means, start by creating a copy
df_complete = df.copy()

# Use the set of considered window sizes in this loop
for ws in [51, 45, 55]:
    r = df.rolling(window=ws, center=False).mean()

    # Give the following names to the columns with rolling windows: X_S, 
    # where X - name of data column and S - current window size
    r.columns = ["%s_%d" % (c, ws) for c in r.columns]

    # Add new columns to the aggregate dataframe (align using index)
    df_complete = pd.concat([df_complete, r], axis=1)

print(df_complete.sample(5))
```

Sample output:

```
       A    B    C        A_51        B_51        C_51        A_45  \
584  169  624  332  407.372549  475.333333  355.784314  405.200000   
863  477  726  218  444.980392  429.431373  458.901961  469.311111   
994  162  161  301  407.843137  415.431373  396.117647  417.155556   
873  600   82  413  445.137255  402.411765  471.490196  433.955556   
6    381  274  681         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   

           B_45        C_45        A_55        B_55        C_55  
584  467.622222  350.755556  409.890909  462.800000  354.490909  
863  448.777778  481.400000  449.418182  416.309091  448.563636  
994  401.555556  400.688889  405.036364  406.309091  383.454545  
873  392.822222  469.577778  454.945455  415.872727  474.327273  
6           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Keep in mind that `NaN` shows up at the beginning of each of the columns with rolling means, where row number is less than the corresponding window size (can't compute such means). Such `NaN`s can be addressed after the `df_complete` dataframe is created, e.g., `df_complete.dropna()`.

Regarding your code (specifically, `test` function), I'd like to point out that according to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html, the specified function needs to "produce a single value from an ndarray input", while you are trying to return means for multiple columns. It seems to me that there is no need to create a custom function for something as common as mean().

I tried using the `rolling_mean()` function suggested in the comment:

```
r = pd.rolling_mean(df, window=51, center=False)
```

but this produces a warning, suggesting to use the line from the solution above:

```
pd.rolling_mean is deprecated for DataFrame and will be removed in a future version, replace with 
    DataFrame.rolling(window=51,center=False).mean()
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel."
```

I hope you find this code and the comments useful.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help and solution! However, the problem I have is to calculate three different means per column individually in a first step which should be realized by the for-loops. This works great outside the pd.rolling window. But inside I always get the **IndexError: too many indices for array** error